# Do any boost::asio async calls automatically time out?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a client and server using `boost::asio` asynchronously. I want to add some timeouts to close the connection and potentially retry if something goes wrong.

My initial thought was that any time I call an `async_` function I should also start a `deadline_timer` to expire after I expect the async operation to complete. Now I'm wondering if that is strictly necessary in every case.

For example:

- `async_resolve` presumably uses the system's resolver which has timeouts built into it (e.g. `RES_TIMEOUT` in `resolv.h` possibly overridden by configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf`). By adding my own timer, I may conflict with how the user wants his resolver to work.
- For `async_connect`, the `connect(2)` syscall has some sort of timeout built into it
- etc.

So which (if any) `async_` calls are guaranteed to call their handlers within a "reasonable" time frame? And if an operation [can|does] timeout would the handler be passed the `basic_errors::timed_out` error or something else?

Comment: I've had to stick to creating my own `deadline_timer` as well, so I would be very interested to see if that's unnecessary.

Comment: +1 interesting question. I think the answer would be largely platform dependent. I'm assuming you care about Linux?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So I did some testing. Based on my results, it's clear that they depend on the underlying OS implementation. For reference, I tested this with a stock Fedora kernel: `2.6.35.10-74.fc14.x86_64`.

The bottom line is that `async_resolve()` looks to be the only case where you *might* be able to get away without setting a `deadline_timer`. It's practically required in every other case for reasonable behavior.

---

**`async_resolve()`**

A call to `async_resolve()` resulted in 4 queries 5 seconds apart. The handler was called 20 seconds after the request with the error `boost::asio::error::host_not_found`.

My resolver defaults to a timeout of 5 seconds with 2 attempts (`resolv.h`), so it appears to send twice the number of queries configured. The behavior is modifiable by setting `options timeout` and `options attempts` in `/etc/resolv.conf`. In every case the number of queries sent was double whatever `attempts` was set to and the handler was called with the `host_not_found` error afterwards.

For the test, the single configured nameserver was black-hole routed.

---

**`async_connect()`**

Calling `async_connect()` with a black-hole-routed destination resulted in the handler being called with the error `boost::asio::error::timed_out` after ~189 seconds.

The stack sent the initial SYN and 5 retries. The first retry was sent after 3 seconds, with the retry timeout doubling each time (3+6+12+24+48+96=189). The number of retries can be changed:

```
% sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
```

The default of 5 is chosen to comply with RFC 1122 (4.2.3.5):

> [The retransmission timers] for a SYN
>   segment MUST be set large enough to
>   provide retransmission of the segment
>   for at least 3 minutes.  The
>   application can close the connection
>   (i.e., give up on the open attempt)
>   sooner, of course.

3 minutes = 180 seconds, though the RFC doesn't appear to specify an upper bound. There's nothing stopping an implementation from retrying forever.

---

**`async_write()`**

As long as the socket's send buffer wasn't full, this handler was always called right away.

My test established a TCP connection and set a timer to call `async_write()` a minute later. During the minute where the connection was established but prior to the `async_write()` call, I tried all sorts of mayhem:

- Setting a downstream router to black-hole subsequent traffic to the destination.
- Clearing the session in a downstream firewall so it would reply with spoofed RSTs from the destination.
- Unplugging my Ethernet
- Running `/etc/init.d/network stop`

No matter what I did, the next `async_write()` would immediately call its handler to report success.

In the case where the firewall spoofed the RST, the connection was closed immediately, but I had no way of knowing that until I attempted the *next* operation (which would immediately report `boost::asio::error::connection_reset`). In the other cases, the connection would remain open and not report errors to me until it eventually timed out 17-18 minutes later.

The worst case for `async_write()` is if the host is retransmitting and the send buffer is full. If the buffer is full, `async_write()` won't call its handler until the retransmissions time out. Linux defaults to 15 retransmissions:

```
% sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_retries2
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15
```

The time between the retransmissions increases after each (and is based on many factors such as the estimated round-trip time of the specific connection) but is clamped at 2 minutes. So with the default 15 retransmissions and worst-case 2-minute timeout, the upper bound is 30 minutes for the `async_write()` handler to be called. When it is called, error is set to `boost::asio::error::timed_out`.

---

**`async_read()`**

This should never call its handler as long as the connection is established and no data is received. I haven't had time to test it.

Comment: This one should be the answer... gives much more relevent detail than what my short answer was.

Answer (score 10):

Those two calls MAY have timeouts that get propigated up to your handlers, but you might be supprised at the length of time it takes before either of those times out. (I know I have let a connection just sit and try to connect on a single connect call for over 10 minutes with `boost::asio` before killing the process). Also the `async_read` and `async_write` calls do not have timeouts associated with them, so if you wish to have timeouts on your reads and writes, you will still need a `deadline_timer`.

Comment: +1 when in doubt, be explicit. Add your own timers if the behavior is not documented.

Comment: Yep. This is pretty much what I found. Though `async_read` and `async_write` *do* have timeouts in the sense that excessive retransmissions will eventually cause the connection to close after tens of minutes.